# How can i browse laravel application on wordpress website?

Tags: laravel

I have a website which is build in wordpress and another application which is build on laravel. I want to browse the laravel application from wordpress folder structure.
How can i make it possible ?

*http://www.example.com -> primary website*
*http://www.example.com/app -> laravel application*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: inside wordpress `root` foldder make `app` folder and past laravel code there

Comment: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444 
where app is my laravel appilication folder

Comment: u need to upload correct vendor folder in `app` or inside `app` folder run `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. create app folder on primary website folder
2. upload and config laravel project on app folder
3. create the .htaccess file so that it contains the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```